# Dynamically component doesn't work in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to add a dynamic component in React, but it is not working. I am getting correct component name, but looks like my variable is not working in it:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const currentLocation = this.props.location.pathname;
    let route_name = 'Dashboard';
    for (let i = 0; i < Route.length; i++) {
      if (Route[i].path == currentLocation) {
        route_name = Route[i].name;
        break;
      }
    }
    this.setState({
      route_name: route_name
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="admin-content">
        <this.state.route_name />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

In order for you to render a component by name directly, you need to assign it to a varaible first and then render it

```
componentDidMount() {
    const currentLocation = this.props.location.pathname;
    let route_name = 'Dashboard';
    for (let i = 0; i < Route.length; i++) {
      if (Route[i].path == currentLocation) {
        route_name = Route[i].name;
        break;
      }
    }
    this.setState({
      route_name: route_name
    });
  }

  render() {
    const RouteName = this.state.route_name;
    return (
      <div className="admin-content">
        <RouteName/>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately for me it throws this error `<HeroBanner /> is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements.` HeroBanner is name of my component and its already pascal case @shubham